# Weighted mean formula for two groups of unequal size

Tags: matlab, weighted-mean

I am very confused with the weighted mean formula. [Wikipedia lists the formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) as $\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_{i}x_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_{i}}$. The article also includes a basic numerical example, as follows:

> Given two school classes, one with 20 students, and one with 30 students, the grades in each class on a test were:
>
> Morning class = 62, 67, 71, 74, 76, 77, 78, 79, 79, 80, 80, 81, 81, 82, 83, 84, 86, 89, 93, 98
>
> Afternoon class = 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 87, 88, 88, 89, 89, 89, 90, 90, 90, 90, 91, 91, 91, 92, 92, 93, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99
>
> The straight average for the morning class is 80 and the straight average of the afternoon class is 90. The straight average of 80 and 90 is 85, the mean of the two class means. However, this does not account for the difference in number of students in each class (20 versus 30); hence the value of 85 does not reflect the average student grade (independent of class). The average student grade can be obtained by averaging all the grades, without regard to classes (add all the grades up and divide by the total number of students):
>
> $$\bar{x} = \frac{4300}{50} = 86$$
>
> Or, this can be accomplished by weighting the class means by the number of students in each class (using a weighted mean of the class means):
>
> $$\bar{x} = \frac{(20\times80) + (30\times90)}{20 + 30} = 86$$

However, when I tried calculating this for myself in MATLAB, I obtained the answer 86.9231 rather than 86. The weight I assigned to all data in "Morning class" is 0.4 and "Afternoon class" is 0.6. Could some one explain why? The code showing my confusion is below:

```
mc = [62, 67, 71, 74, 76, 77, 78, 79, 79, 80, 80, 81, 81, 82, 83, 84, 86, 89, 93, 98];
ac = [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 87, 88, 88, 89, 89, 89, 90, 90, 90, 90, 91, 91, ...
      91, 92, 92, 93, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99];
avg_mc = mean(mc); % = 80
avg_ac = mean(ac); % = 90
len_mc = length(mc);
len_ac = length(ac);
weight_mc = len_mc/(len_mc+len_ac);
weight_ac = len_ac/(len_mc+len_ac);
weighted_mean = weight_mc * avg_mc + weight_ac * avg_ac; % = 86
mc2 = mc .* weight_mc;
ac2 = ac .* weight_ac;
weighted_mean2 = (sum(mc2) + sum(ac2)) / (weight_mc * len_mc + weight_ac * len_ac); 
  % = 86.9231
```

Comment: We won't be able to answer this question unless you disclose the details of your application of the formula.  Presently you seem to be saying that you attempted to carry out the illustrated calculation in the Wikipedia article, $$0.4\times 80 + 0.6\times 90,$$ but that you didn't get $86$ as the answer. Maybe you should find a working calculator?

Comment: Show us the calculation you did which did not produce the answer, 86.

Comment: That's because your weights of the morning class and afternoon class are wrong when using the above formula.  The weights of the morning class and afternoon class should be (think about it)..... ;)

Comment: How did you come up with your formula for weighted_mean2 ?  Put another way, why would you think that is a correct calculation?  If you changed your last line to (sum(mc2)  / len_mc ) + (sum(ac2)/ len_ac), it would be correct. By including the weight_mc and weight_ac as multipliers of len_mc and len_ac, you're in effect "double counting" the weights (well, not exactly double, but not exactly once).

Comment: @gung, your editing has made the code not directly (without fix-up) copy and paste (MATLAB) executable, but it was before editing.  That is due to line-wrap.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, I don't have MATLAB, & haven't used in in >10 years. I didn't know. Can MATLAB really not handle the line wrap?

Comment: @gung, with use of .... at end of line to be continued, yes.  As is above on my computer, no.  The above come through as separate lines, so need ... or separately copy and paste each line onto big line.  There are some "programs" in which lines get wrapped for display purposes, but when copied and pasted, are not separated into separate lines, and in such cases, the ... is not needed, since MATLAB sees in effect the whole non-wrapped line.  Perhaps it has to do with carriage return, and might vary between LINUUX(UNIX) and WINDOWS. Anyhow, just having the original long lines works directly.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, interesting. It works fine in R to have a carriage return in the middle of a line. I find code that can't be seen in the window to be annoying. I'll add the ellipsis.

Comment: @gung, thanks, but you need to do it for the weighted_mean2 line as well.

Comment: Wikipedia articles are very prone to editing so I have incorporated the relevant text here; this also has the advantage of making the question self-contained. I think the mistake in the code reveals what is, at heart, a statistical misunderstanding of this particular application of the weighted mean (taking the overall average of two groups of unequal size, based on the group means) and so have voted to reopen. The same conceptual mistake could just as well have been made typing the numbers into a pocket calculator.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, OK. I didn't edit that line originally; it was already like that.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, the formula for weighted_mean2 is a realization of the formula bar(x) = sum(weights*values) / sum(weights) which is given in the first line of this question? I don't understand what's wrong about it?

Comment: @ Philip2011 , in this "scenario", each individual data point is not supposed to get different weights. In this case, all len_mc + len_ac individual data points are equally weighted.  The 2 different weights only come into play if we want to consider the averages of mc and ac as being 1 data point each (i.e., one data point for mc, and one data point for ac); then we apply the Wikipedia weighted average formula to combine the averages of mc and ac. What you have done with weighted_mean2 is to more heavily weight each individual data point in ac than each individual data point in mc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this has now been taken off hold, I will re-enter my comment, which was in effect an answer, as an answer.

In the Wikipedia article example, each individual data point is not supposed to get different weights. In this case, all len_mc + len_ac number of individual data points are equally weighted. The 2 different weights (in this case, 0.4 and 0.6) only come into play if we want to consider the averages of mc and ac as being 1 data point each (i.e., one data point for mc, and one data point for ac); then we apply the Wikipedia weighted average formula to combine the averages of mc and ac. What you have done with weighted_mean2 is to more heavily weight each individual data point in ac than each individual data point in mc, and that is why you don't get the correct answer - or put another way, you have solved a different ("wrong") problem.